# Can't convert timestamp to date properly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, timestamp

I use mongodb as my database and in that db I have a timestamp field but I haven't seen any format similar to that. Some of them are:

```
1657479170.7300725
1657479170.7301126
1657479170.7301197
1657479170.9120467
1657479170.932398
```

When i try to convert this to normal date format (YYYY-MM-DD) I get the correct date. For example the converted date of the first timestamp above is:

```
10.07.2022 21:52:50
```

However when I try to convert it in javascript I get:

```
1970-01-20 06:24:39
```

which is definitely not correct value.

My code for the conversion :

```
ConvH.forEach(conv => {
    conv.tracker.events.forEach(element => {
        console.log(parseFloat( parseFloat(element.timestamp.toFixed(4))),  moment(new Date( parseFloat( element.timestamp.toFixed(4)))).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
        element.timestamp = new Date(element.timestamp).toLocaleString();
        
    })
});
```

*Note : new Date(element.timestamp).toLocaleString(); gives the same thing :/*

Comment: It thinks your date is an epoch date (milliseconds after 1st Jan 1970), which is why your date is so close to 1970. Look here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/

Comment: I looked over it but I don't understand what I am supposed to do. In my data there is a dot and after that there are some numbers :/

Comment: The value appears to be seconds since 1 Jan 1970 (a fairly common epoch in computing that is also used by ECMAScript/javascript). However, ECMASecript uses milliseconds so just multiply the value by 3 to get milliseconds and provide to the *Date* constructor: `new Date(1657479170.7300725 * 1e3)` produces a *Date* for 2022-07-10T18:52:50.730Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `new Date(timestamp.getHighBits() * 1000)`

Comment: `ConvH.forEach(conv => {
    conv.tracker.events.forEach(element => {
        console.log(new Date(timestamp.getHighBits() * 1000));
        
    })
});` I wrote like this and it gives the following error : TypeError: element.timestamp.getHighBits is not a function

Comment: I think since it's type Number, I don't need to use getHishBits function.